# Prove that matrices commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $I$ be the identity matrix, $S$ any stochastic matrix and  $a \in (0,1)$.  How can we prove that
$$(I-S) \text { and } (I-aS)^{-1}$$
are commutative?

Comment: Since $0 < a < 1$, I think you can write $(I-aS)^{-1}$ as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^nS^n.$$ $I$ and $S$ commute with any power of $S$, so the result should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
(I-S)(I-aS)^{-1} =\\ 
[(1 - 1/a)I+(I/a-S)](I-aS)^{-1} =\\
\frac{a-1}{a}(I-aS)^{-1}+\frac 1a(I-aS)(I-aS)^{-1} = \\
\frac{a-1}{a}(I-aS)^{-1}+\frac 1a(I-aS)^{-1}(I-aS) =\dots\\
$$

Comment: Neat observation. I like your way better than my suggestion. Although I think the requirement that $0 < a < 1$ kind of gets swallowed up in your proof.

Answer (score 3):

For any matrix $A$, we have that $I, A, \lambda A$ commute for any scalar $\lambda$.

If $I-\lambda A$ is invertible, then $A (A-\lambda I) = (A-\lambda I) A$ and so
(pre- and post-multiplying by $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$) we see that $A$ and 
$(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ commute.

Hence any polynomial in $A$ commutes with any polynomial in $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$.

Comment: This is very nice. When I read the question, my first thought was to invoke Cayley-Hamilton theorem, which, given your answer, is surely a big overkill.